# MKMapView moving Annotations Automatically - animate them?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a data set of annotations that can update very quickly.  At the moment I remove all annotations before replotting them back onto the map.

```
NSArray *existingpoints = [mapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(self isKindOfClass: %@)", [MKUserLocation class]]];
[mapView removeAnnotations:existingpoints];
```

I calculate where they are anyway within the custom object so would like to be able to call this and "move" the annotation without removing and re-adding it back to the map.  The example call I make which works and I would like to almost "poll" is below.

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = [lat doubleValue];
    coord.longitude = [lon doubleValue];


        double differencetime = exampleTime;
        double speedmoving;
        double distanceTravelled = speedmoving * differencetime;

        CLLocationDistance movedDistance = distanceTravelled;
        double radiansHeaded = DEG2RAD([self.heading doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *newLocation = [passedLocation newLoc:movedDistance along:radiansHeaded];
        coord = newLocation.coordinate;

    return coord;
}
```

As requested, the .h file of the Object, I do not have a SetCoordinate method..

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface TestObject : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{
    NSString *adshex;
    NSString *lat;
    NSString *lon;


    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *adshex;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *lat;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *lon;


@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;


- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;

@end
```

Comment: Do you have a setCoordinate method in your annotation object or just the coordinate method?  Show the .h file for your annotation object.

Comment: No I do not, added the .h to the edit

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you update the annotation's coordinate using a setCoordinate method (or equivalent), the map view will automatically update the position of the annotation on the view.  [This page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) in the docs says the following:

> Important: When you implement the
>   coordinate property in your class, it
>   is recommended that you synthesize its
>   creation. If you choose to implement
>   the methods for this property
>   yourself, or if you manually modify
>   the variable underlying that property
>   in other parts of your class after the
>   annotation has been added to the map,
>   be sure to send out key-value
>   observing (KVO) notifications when you
>   do. Map Kit uses KVO notifications to
>   detect changes to the coordinate,
>   title, and subtitle properties of your
>   annotations and make any needed
>   changes to the map display. If you do
>   not send out KVO notifications, the
>   position of your annotations may not
>   be updated properly on the map.

The map view will only know to re-read the coordinate property of the annotation if it's told (via KVO) that the coordinate has changed.  One way to do that is implement a setCoordinate method and call that wherever you have the code that updates the annotation's location.

In your code, you are re-calculating the coordinate in the readonly coordinate property itself.  What you could do is add this to the annotation .m file (and to the .h):

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    //do nothing
}
```

and in the place where you update locations, call the setCoordinate method on the annotation:

```
[someAnnotation setCoordinate:someAnnotation.coordinate];
```

You could do this in the place where you currently remove/re-add the annotations.

The above call looks funny because you have the coordinate re-calc in the coordinate-getter method.  Although it should work as a quick fix/test, I don't recommend using it regularly.

Instead, you could re-calc the annotation's location outside (where you currently remove/re-add the annotations) and pass the new coordinate to setCoordinate.  Your annotation object could store its new location in the lat/lng ivars you currently have (set them in the setCoordinate and use only those to construct a CLLocationCoordinate2D to return from the getter) or (better) use the coordinate ivar itself (set it in setCoordinate and return it in the getter).

Comment: The link to the "Important" note has changed: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW2

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't animate the transition at all. Anyone know of any way to move an annotation animatedly?

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:2.2
                                             animations:^{ [tempPlacemark setCoordinate:newAnnoView.coordinate]; }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished){  }];