# Update mapview annotations every second with new coordinates Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations, mkmapview, android-mapview

I know there are a few questions about this but i just cant seem to find any good answer to the question. What I am doing is fetching information from a db and collect the info into annotations on a map in `mapview` (Iphone).

What I want is to update the information from the database every second or so and update the annotations so that the new locations is shown on the map. So for instance if coordinates are moving it will show the movement every second. Are there any standard methods for this or any other good fixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[yourAnnotation setCoordinate:newCoordinate];`

Pls see if this SO question helps you [MKMapView moving Annotations Automatically - animate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113085/mkmapview-moving-annotations-automatically-animate-them)