# Remove Callout from Mapview

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I want to remove the default callout from the map view and want to have my custom callout with an image. Can anyone please tell me how to remove the default callout from the Map ?

Comment: [annotationView setCanShowCallout:NO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was originally written as an answer for this question:

[MKAnnotationView - Lock custom annotation view to pin on location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392931/mkannotationview-lock-custom-annotation-view-to-pin-on-location-updates/7363862#7363862)

Also see answers for this question:

[How to customize the callout bubble for MKAnnotationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/customize-callout-bubble-for-annotationview)