# How to add Custom UIView as MKMapView Overlay

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have seen many sample to display images or polygons over `MKOverlayRenderer`. But I need to display a `UIView` with some images and labels on `MKOverlayRenderer`. I need to do this on iPhone, not iPad. SO We cannot use UIPopoverController. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793315/customize-mkannotation-callout-view/30795086#30795086    May this help u.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392931/mkannotationview-lock-custom-annotation-view-to-pin-on-location-updates.). This [demo](https://github.com/jacobjennings/JJMapCallout) project solved the problem. I customised that project and used in my application.