# MKAnnotation is not moving with map after update the position

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, ios11

[On first time load, it's working fine and move along with MapView, but if I change the marker position and then if I drag the map view that marker is not moving with map.it's just stuck on that place. It's only happening in iOS 11 or below that version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNk2o.png)

[See the  screenshot its just stuck  that place.moving mapview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD5ib.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this will work, but you can change coordinate of annoation  use

```
[yourAnnotation setCoordinate:newCoordinate];
```

Pls see if this SO question helps you [MKMapView moving Annotations Automatically - animate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113085/mkmapview-moving-annotations-automatically-animate-them) ?